# Check for iPhone 4 & 5s - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, size-classes

Is there any alternative to check for iPhone 4s, 5 & 5s screen width (has equal value 320) other than [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width?

Infact I want to check if its only iPhone 4s,5 or 5s. If I use size classes, it might include iPhone 6 as part of Compact Width & any Height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this awesome library](https://github.com/duhovny/DeviceHardware) to detect what type of device the app is on. Right up to iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: It is a nice library and I use it, however note that on a simulator the device is always a simulator - aka you need actual devices for testing.  Testing on a device is always better, but not everyone has access to such an array of devices.

Comment: This is the only caveat. You cannot detect what type of device you're simulating. As you correctly pointed out - test on actual devices, where possible.